# ssh freezes when trying to connect to some hosts

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

When I try to ssh to particular machine/s in a list, The SSH command happens to be freezing. I tried out setting ssh timeout. But then also it's freezes even after the timeout.

In verbose mode :

```
OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x358.x.server.com [10.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /export/home/sqlrpt/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /export/home/sqlrpt/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /export/home/sqlrpt/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
```

At this point it freezes.

A work around I thought was to create a child process for each ssh calls and if the process doesn't respond after a timeout - Kill it.
But are there any less complex ways, so that I can accommodate it in a shell script itself  rather than going for a C/C++ program ?

Comment: Try running the ssh command with -vv or even -vvv to increase verbosity - you might get more information that way.

Comment: Programming question or admin question?

Comment: Why such ancient versions of OpenSSH & OpenSSL?

Comment: Can't help it much as they are managed by a different colo. and the only way is just to go with this :|

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -2 -o ConnectTimeout=5
```

This did the trick. It's no more getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

probably, you found this bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=143316
it was duplicated here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=133884 , and there is a workaround for it

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_default_win_scale
```

Comment: can you make it more clear? What really is the work around ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same kind of annoying problem with openSuse 11.4 (x86_64) (kernel 2.6.37.6-24-desktop), SSH-version: OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010.

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling
```

Did the trick and problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the host's internet.This has happened to me several times.Right before ssh turn the hosts internet off and then back on.